# Самописная база данных

Tags: база-данных, rust

Привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, по какому алгоритму строится бд. Хочу написать ее на rust, но не знаю, как все устроено. Если все сохранять в массив, то при закрытии все исчезнет, вопрос в том, как сохранить информацию, полученную в результате запроса, в бд? Или создать файл и в нем сохранять?
Расскажите, пожалуйста!  Спасибо!

Comment: Для начала нужно прочитать пару книг и несколько десятков научных статей.

Comment: "Садитесь в кружок, ребятишки, до ужина есть полчаса. Сейчас расскажу я вам ..." (Спайк Миллиган) - "... по какому алгоритму строится бд". И ведь расскажут же!

Comment: Если вы серьезны в своих намерениях, могу для введения в тему предложить прочитать *Джеффри Д. Ульман, Дженнифер Уидом: Введение в системы баз данных*

Comment: Насколько помню в очень старой книжке [RISS: система управления реляционными базами данных](http://books-loading.net/9641-riss-sistema-upravlenija-reljacionnymi-bazami.html) был даже код СУБД. Может интересно будет ознакомиться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, сохранять либо в файл либо в память, а в последствии все равно в файл, но эти слова не помогут вам с такой задачей, ибо ваш вопрос это огромная и обширная тема, поищите лучше соответствующую литературу.

Например:

[1] - *Джеффри Д. Ульман, Дженнифер Уидом*: **Введение в системы баз данных**
<sub>По совету @Nofate♦</sub>
[2] - [*RISS*: **система управления реляционными базами данных**](http://books-loading.net/9641-riss-sistema-upravlenija-reljacionnymi-bazami.html)
<sub>По совету @avp</sub>